# How to avoid stack overflow with gorm?

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

First, database is created with `sqlite3 test.db < schema.sql`.

Contents of `schema.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE y (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    x_id INTEGER REFERENCES x
);
```

Then the program is run with `go run main.go`.

Contents of `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
)

type X struct {
    ID   uint
    Name string
    Ys   []*Y
}

type Y struct {
    ID   uint
    Name string
    X    *X     `gorm:"column:x_id"`
}

func (X) TableName() string {
    return "x"
}

func (Y) TableName() string {
    return "y"
}

func main() {
    db, _ := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})

    x := &X{Name: "X"}
    y := &Y{Name: "Y", X: x}
    x.Ys = []*Y{y}

    db.Create(&x)
}
```

After which `fatal error: stack overflow` is thrown.

I guess it has something to do with the recursive nature of the structs and objects involved. When I comment out the `Ys []*Y` line along with `y := &Y{Name: "Y", X: x}` and `x.Ys = []*Y{y}` it successfully inserts "X" into table `x`, but when I comment out the `Ys []*Y` and `x.Ys = []*Y{y}` only and change `db.Create(&x)` to `db.Create(&y)` nothing gets inserted in either table.

**EDIT**

It saves `x` and `y` when `y := &Y{Name: "Y", X: x}` is changed to `y := &Y{Name: "Y"}`, but with `x_id` as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Valuer interface did the trick.

```
func (x X) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return int64(x.ID), nil
}
```

https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html